# Hosting a Google App Engine app on my own server

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is the following possible?

I want to host app that processes favicons from URLs, like getFavicon does.

Site: http://g.etfv.co Source: https://github.com/potatolondon/getfavicon.

I have emailed the creator last week to inquire about the title of this post, with no response. I see that there is a lot of Python involved, and simply putting the files on my server doesn't do anything.

Comment: With Google App Engine you can run it as a dummy on a local machine and connect to whatever port you launched it on, with option 0.0.0.0 as ip. This is convenient for testing of, for example, Flask apps.

Comment: @BHM That's great, but I would rather run this on my own server. You never know when Google is going to shut down services, and I'd rather rely on myself.

Comment: Then I'd say the answer is `not possible`, but wonder what's the point with the question? Why make something for a framework where you do not trust the framework provider?

Comment: @BHM I didn't make the app and I don't want to use the framework. I want to know how to set up my server so it can run the app.

Comment: Sorry; but that's not what I would expect of a `SO` question. How-to's are up to the framework providers to provide.

Comment: @BHM I'm not looking for a how-to, I just want a point in the right direction. I can search all I want, but unless I know how to pinpoint precisely what I need, it won't matter. Then again, if I knew that, this question wouldn't be here.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but cannot help you. I think the problem needs to be broken into several smaller questions, such as: What is the architecture that you pursue? G app engine is just a PaaS.

Comment: @BHM Hmm, okay. I didn't know it was a PaaS. Thanks for communicating. I suppose that would explain the downvotes, I was apparently supposed to know that already.

Comment: Yeah. Don't worry too much about downvotes. They are just indicators that you've missed something that apparently is obvious to those in field. We all get that from time to time. Check out docker (www.docker.com) the CTO's intro is a pretty good place to start. I hope that can send you off in the right direction :-)

Comment: @BHM Docker looks promising! Not deleting this question, to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>I found something similar written for node.JS and forked it here: https://github.com/IdeasNeverCease/getFavicon.</del>

EDIT: This code fulfills my original request, which was to load favicons, no matter the URL:

```
var getFavicon = function () {

    var favicon, _tabID = $(".tab.active").attr("data-tab");
    var nodeList = $("iframe" + _tabID).contents().find("link");

    for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
        // get any type of icon
        if ((nodeList[i].getAttribute("rel") == "icon") || (nodeList[i].getAttribute("rel") == "shortcut icon") || (nodeList[i].getAttribute("rel") == "apple-touch-icon")) {
            favicon = nodeList[i].href; // get absolute path
        }
    }

    return favicon;

};
```